# Dolist evaluation error

Tags: common-lisp

I'm a CommonLisp noob with a question.  I have these two functions below.

A helper function:

```
(defun make-rests (positions rhythm)
  "now make those positions negative numbers for rests"
  (let ((resultant-rhythm rhythm))
    (dolist (i positions resultant-rhythm)
      (setf (nth i resultant-rhythm) (* (nth i resultant-rhythm) -1)))))
```

And a main function:

```
(defun test-return-rhythms (rhythms)
  (let ((positions '((0 1) (0)))
        (result nil))
    (dolist (x positions (reverse result))
      (push (make-rests x rhythms) result))))
```

When I run `(test-return-rhythms '(1/4 1/8))`, it  evaluates to: `((1/4 -1/8) (1/4 -1/8))`

However, I expected: `(test-return-rhythms '(1/4 1/8))` to evaluate to: `((-1/4 -1/8) (-1/4 1/8))`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `make-rests` is destructive.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *rhythm* '(1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4))
*RHYTHM*
CL-USER> (make-rests '(0 2) *rhythm*)
(-1/4 1/4 -1/4 1/4)
CL-USER> *rhythm*
(-1/4 1/4 -1/4 1/4)
```

So, if you run your test, the second iteration will see `(-1/4 -1/8)`, and `(make-rests '(0) '(-1/4 -1/8))` returns `(1/4 -1/8)`. Your use of `let` in `make-rests` does not copy the list, it just creates a new binding that references it. Use `copy-list` in your `let`, or write a non-destructive version in the first place:

```
(defun make-rests (positions rhythm)
  (loop for note in rhythm
        for i from 0
        collect (if (member i positions) (* note -1) note)))
```

Comment: Ah, and note that this function would be better named `toggle-rests`.